# Close similar question?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5563859/alternative-mobile-advertiser-networks-for-android/6262918) got closed recently. I figured the reason it got closed probably is because it's sort of a "polling" question and "is there any good..." is rather subjective.
However, I just stumbled upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/86083/any-good-recommendations-for-mp3-sound-libraries-for-java) and to me it seems that the nature of that question is the same. So, why would the first question be closed and the other one not?

I did find a post on meta, where someone asked a [similar question as this one](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/119748/why-is-my-question-closed-while-similar-question-is-open-in-another-tag). The answer was that the other question was created years ago when rules weren't as strict. The result was that both questions got closed, so shouldn't the 2nd question (on the mp3 libraries) be closed as well?

Comment: You don't perceive any kind of quality difference between those two questions?

Comment: I have no idea what you're talking about.  They're both closed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

StackOverflow has almost three quadrillion questions, and about a bajillion more come flooding in every day.  Those are official numbers, btw.

So, it is quite easy for a question to slip by that normally would be closed.  In fact, the question you used as an example *wasn't flagged*, so it would have required a moderator randomly stumble across it in order for it to be closed.

Really, this question isn't constructive at all.  I'm sure there are *tens of thousands* of similar examples on SO right now; asking a meta question for each one wouldn't be practical.

If you see a bad question, please flag it.  If your flag gets declined, *then* consider whether its worth asking about it on meta.